# Datepicker to datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

We currently working on a Hotel Management System, and we have an accommodation module. In our accommodation module there's Start Date and End Date, we used date picker for it. But I was ask to make it a datetime picker, I search about it and I find something on how to do it. I download a datetimepicker jquery plugin. Here's what I did in my UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $('#_startDate_id').datetimepicker();
       $('#_endDate_id').datetimepicker();
     });
</script>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
     <input type='text' class="form-control" id='_startDate_id' />
</div>

<div class='col-sm-6'>
     <input type='text' class="form-control" id='_endDate_id' />
</div>
```

But I'm a bit confused on how to adjust my domain, this how it looks like:

```
@NotNull
@PresentOrFuture
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;

@NotNull
@Future
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
```

Newbie here. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by **how to adjust my domain**?

Comment: I mean, should I change my data type Sir?

Comment: Kendall I am not sir, I am a developer like you, **$('#_startDate_id').datetimepicker();** is enough to call datetime picker. You will the selected value and use it accoedingly

Comment: Which jquery are you using for datetimepicker ?

Comment: Really not clear what the specific problem is...or even if there is one. Start with what is or isn't working and if you have any errors in browser console or on server